# Oculus Virtual Desktop for MacBook Pro with ad-hoc network

Tags: networking, macos, wireless-networking, vmware-fusion, virtual-desktop

I'm trying to use Oculus to do Virtual Desktop with my MacBook Pro M1.

I tried Virtual Desktop streamer for Mac, but it is too slow.

I used Virtual Desktop streamer for Windows 11 using virtualization on Macbook Pro using VMware Fusion. It actually works well.

But one thing is, Virtual Desktop requires wireless network. If I'm at a coffeeshop and the Wi-Fi doesn't work, I want to be self-reliant. I tried wired network connection - it doesn't really work.

What I want to try is to get a ad-hoc network that connects my Windows-virtualized to my Oculus. I don't have a router (maybe I could bring a router to the cofeeshop?), but I do have a Windows Surface Pro X that can do a hotspot. Would a router fix the problem?

What I did was I did bridged Wi-fi on my virtualized-Windows to make my ip address for Windows: 192.168.137.18. It is connected to Wi-Fi let's call, "Surface-Hotspot." The situation is: VMware Fusion is simulating a Ethernet internet that connects to my MacBook's Wi-Fi which connects to "Surface Hotspot."

The IP for Oculus connected to Surface-Hotspot is 192.168.137.22 (22 is an example).

When I try to connect on Virtual Desktop, it says "on a different network," it does measuring bandwidth, but says, it ultimately cannot connect.

Is there a way to do this? Is there just a setting for the IP addresses that I need to do?

Or should I buy a router?

Is there simply a better setup/solution to this problem?

---

**Edit**: One solution I created was this - use my old Android phone to create a hotspot (without any cellular data) that connects my MacBook Pro virtualized-Windows and Oculus. It works.

Now, I just need to buy a Wifi adapter so that my MacBook can connect to the internet (2nd Wi-Fi adapter) while connecting to Oculus (1st/original Wi-Fi adapter).

But I'd like to hear other solutions.

---

**Edit 2**: I created a perfect solution!

My Android creates a hotspot that connects my MacBook and Oculus.  My iPhone, which has cellular data, does a hotspot that my Android connects to with Wi-Fi.

I have internet, and the internet data is not being used by the local MacBook-Oculus connection (saves data). In summary, Android is Wi-Fi to iPhone and Hotspot to MacBook-Oculus.

It's a perfect setup.

---

One solution I created was this - use my old Android phone to create a hotspot (without any cellular data) that connects my MacBook Pro virtualized-Windows and Oculus. It works.

Now, I just need to buy a Wi-Fi adapter so that my MacBook can connect to the internet (2nd Wi-Fi adapter) while connecting to Oculus (1st/original Wi-Fi adapter).

But I'd like to hear other solutions.

Comment: I can't tell from your description what the real problem is. Also beware that the term "ad-hoc network" specifically means an IBSS network, where nothing acts as an AP (i.e. nothing acts as a wireless router or hotspot). One last thought: macOS's Internet Sharing feature can act as an AP, and macOS also has the ability to participate in ad-hoc (IBSS) networks without any AP. So there's probably no need to bring the Surface Pro into this.

Comment: Hello @Spiff, I am interested in making an IBSS connection between my Mac and Oculus.  How can I do this?  I don't see the setting in Mac settings.

Comment: Your best solution is to get another Wi-Fi adapter for the MacBook. I used to have a setup like this and it works great!

Comment: I think this question may have too much, questionably relevant, information in it that is working to conceal the issue rather than clarify it. Can you edit your question to focus it more clearly on the issue, cutting out information that is not directly related to the issue? Also, it sounds as though you already know a solution and are simply asking for opinions on possible alternatives.